# Setting the Android System Volume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am writing an application which handles the following:

1. Silent - Makes the phone volume silent
2. Low - Makes the phone volume 1 point above the silent
3. Medium - Makes the phone volume medium
4. High - Makes the phone volume maximum

Phone volume includes Ringer, video, audio , games volume etc.

I know how to achieve Silent mode through `AudioManager`. But for 2-4 , I could not find any helpful code snippets. What do I need to do?

Comment: I'd guess ``AudioManager.setStreamVolume(int, int, int)`` should allow you to set specific volume for these settings. As for stream types there seem to be e.g. ``AudioManager.STREAM_RING`` I would expect set volume for ringer.

Answer (score 20):

Add this in `onCreate()` method of your code and then play around with the 0 value to increase or decrease the volume where 0 means OFF.

```
AudioManager mgr=null;

mgr=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out 
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/dealing-with-the-android-media-player/

The steps are:

- get the audio man.
- fetch the required stream.
- call appropriate method on stream.

e.g.:

```
mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

- to get max vol:

  ```
  int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  ```