# How to set speaker volume to lowest?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I need to set speakerphone volume to the lowest possible through Audio Manager. I need the lowest volume index.

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
    (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                             [int value] = ?,
                             0);
```

I did a search on SO, but found nothing usefull.

Comment: for what you need to low the volume for example For  Audio or for Call.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the Android System Volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164347/setting-the-android-system-volume)

Comment: for call, my app turn on the speaker and sets the volume to lowest so user can listen conversation very clearly if he/she have bad mic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 
        AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private AudioManager audio;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Override onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
switch (keyCode) {
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    return true;
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    return true;
default:
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by the below code

```
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
```